# How can I store arbitrary data in LLVM metadata?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to store a set of key-values within a module I am generating using the LLVM C++ API. I would like to store it as metadata, if possible. Is that possible with an unmodified version of LLVM, or would I have to modify it?